# SharePoint 2010: Which publishing feature adds the "Navigation" site settings link?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When publishing is activated on a web, a new "Navigation" link is displayed on the site settings page (which points to **_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx**).

I want to change the permission levels which dictate whether this link is visible on the page, however I can't find the **CustomAction** which installs this link.

Does anyone know which XML file in which feature this is defined in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious that this is an out of the box feature, so you can't modify it without invalidating your support :/

What you could do is build your own feature and use a feature with CustomActions to remove and replace the links to the current page with links to the new page you're creating.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, but I need to know which feature installs the link on the Site Settings page so that I can get its CustomAction ID value.

Comment: Do a text search on features folder

Comment: Thanks Madhur. I found it in the FEATURES\Navigation\NavigationSiteSettings.xml feature file.